# "He/Peter said" vs. "Said he/Peter"

Tags: word-order, reported-speech, inversion, direct-speech

> We often see **"said he/Peter"** or **"he/Peter said"** after the direct speech :

1. "Your information is out of date" he said.
2. "Your information is out of date" said he.
3. "Your information is out of date" Peter said.
4. "Your information is out of date" said Peter.

Is there any rule when to apply and when not to apply this type of inversion after the direct speech?

Comment: The "default" pattern in English is *Subject + Verb + Object* (i.e. ***John said "This text"***), Half of your examples simply relocate the "object" (the words spoken) to the beginning of the utterance, giving *O+S+V*. The more extreme sequence change to *O+V+S* is less common overall, and this is *particularly* the case when the subject is a ***pronoun***. So you'll rarely encounter your example #2 outside of "literary" contexts - *especially* with the first person singular pronoun - *"That's very true", **said I*** is vanishingly unlikely in normal conversational contexts today.

Comment: Can we use either 'O+S+V' or 'O+V+S' when the subject is a **pronoun**?

Comment: As I said, OVS is less common overall than OSV (and *both* of those are less common than the "default" for English, which is SVO). And I also said that we're *particularly* less likely to relocate the "object" to the start of the utterance if the "subject" is a ***pronoun*** (as in your example #2). That doesn't mean any of these forms are "incorrect". It's just that ***in practice, in a real-world conversational context***, native speakers would almost ***never*** come out with an utterance like your example #2 in ***speech*** (but we happily ***read and write*** such things every day).

Comment: All four of these are correct, although (2) *said he* tends to sound either old-fashioned or jocular to my ear.