# 'Said distracted mum' vs 'distracted mum said'?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order, subject-auxiliary-inversion

I write fairytale, and I wonder if I can write something like:

> "'It was strange.' **Said distracted mum**"

or maybe the form "distracted mum said" has to be for every time? I'd like to diversify

Comment: See [“He/Peter said” vs. “Said he/Peter”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/247014/he-peter-said-vs-said-he-peter). But note that when "mum" is being used as a ***proper noun*** (i.e. - as someone's ***name***) it should be capitalised. And personally I think the usage as given is very "poetic / stylised", so maybe that's not ideal. It could be made *slightly* less "unusual" by including the indefinite article *(**a**)* before ***distracted***, but it's still going to attract attention. More naturally, ***"XXX", said Mum, distracted*** (an ordinary adverbial/adjectival construction).

Comment: Is stange a typo for strange?